# Why my plugin is not call in phone gap +android?

Tags: android, cordova

I am making one plugin in android But It is not call any success or error method , can you please explain why it is not call ?

I use **cordova 2.7**

Here is my steps 
1) I write config.xml

```
  <plugin name="Test" value="com.example.plugintest.Test"/>

make java file
package com.example.plugintest;

import org.apache.cordova.CordovaArgs;
import org.apache.cordova.api.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.api.CordovaPlugin;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

import android.util.Log;

public class Test extends CordovaPlugin {


      public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {

          System.out.println("oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo");
        return false;

            }


}

 $(document).ready(function(){
       test();

       });


function test(){ 
alert("=============");


 cordova.exec(onSuccess, onerror, "Test",
                 "execute",[]);
                 }

function onSuccess(){
alert("Success")

}       


function onerror(){
alert("====error===========")

}
```

**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'exec'
CordovaWebView: TIMEOUT ERROR!
```

**

Answer (score 0):

Are you waiting for the "device ready" event? Are you importing your JavaScript part/interface of your plugin in your main JS/HTML file? , give a try to wrap your plugin-call with this:

```
<html>
  <head>  
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.7.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    // Wait for Cordova to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    // Cordova is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        //HERE YOUR PLUG-IN CALL
    }  
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>   
  </body>
</html>
```